# Is it possible to add an mask while expanding the Ext.tree.panel?

Tags: extjs

I have a `Ext.tree.panel`, cause it contains lots of data, i initialize it without the data expanded.

While i want to expand the tree will `expandAll`, it took a bit long(maybe 10 secs). And in the meantime, the browser seem crashed(without any respond).

Therefore, I'd like to have a mask on the tree while expanding it.

But the Ext.LoadMask doesn't work while expanding. I am wondering if there is any other way to  set a mask on top of the component while expanding?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Ext.getCmp('myTreePanel').setLoading(true); and after loading complete Ext.getCmp('myTreePanel').setLoading(false); Maybe it makes sense to load the entire tree structure when the page loads and not use the requests to the server when opens each node?

Comment: I've already done this like you proposed. It didn't work. My guess is, expanding produce different action from loading, therefore, `loadMask` is not the right method to achieve my goal. Do you know if there is another way doing this?

Comment: Then try Ext.MessageBox.wait('message');

Comment: Maybe this example is just what you need?
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/example/tree/locking-buffer-rendered-treegrid.html

Answer (score 0):

It's really a weird issue. When i have done as following:

```
var mask = new Ext.LoadMask(this.treePanel, {}).show();
this.treePanel.expandAll(function() {
    Ext.destroy(mask);
});
```

The `loadingMask` never shown.

But it worked if changed a bit like this:

```
var _this = this;
var mask = new Ext.LoadMask(this.treePanel, {}).show();
setTimeout(function(){
    _this.treePanel.expandAll(function() {
        Ext.destroy(mask);
    });
}, 500);
```

Anyway, problem solved.